# Keeps setting windows-server-2012-r2 up in america (cali) when location is set to australia-southeast1-a

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, ip-address, geolocation

I have just tried to set up 2 back to back servers in Australia but for some reason when the servers deploy they are located in America in California. Any idea how to fix this issue?

Both Zones are set to

```
australia-southeast1-b
australia-southeast1-a
```

[image: IP2location]

[image]

Comment: It says that they are in Mountain View, California Region for both and the zones are "Australia-southeast1-b" -- "Australia-southeast1-a"

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ogzjEFt.png https://i.imgur.com/gjNcRr6.png

Comment: IP geolocation for cloud providers is not necessarily correct. Unless you have a specific reason to mistrust your cloud provider, I would assume that the information from them is more correct then a 3rd party geolocation tool.

Comment: Well, the first time i tried and realised it wasn't in Aus, I signed into my google account on the server and on my security sign in it said the location of the ip was trying to sign in was in America. So that's what prompted my checking

Comment: @Brock Google is using the same prone-to-errors technique, IP geolocation.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all of Google's IP address are registered to their headquarters in Mountain View, California, regardless of where in the world they are actually used. This is true of many companies, of course. Services which purport to tell you where in the world an IP address is located are very often wrong, as is the one you posted in your question.